# Strange result of a fixed effect model

Tags: r, multiple-regression, stata, interpretation, fixed-effects-model

If I am looking at sports data of dozens of soccer leagues over a year:

```
Dependent Variable = Goals Scored

Independent Variables:
X1 = Traditional Home Uniforms
X2 = Retro Home Uniforms
X3 = Secondary Home Uniforms 

Controls:
A whole bunch
Most importantly--Every team has a rank (1-50) from the previous year
```

When I run my regressions clustering my errors on rank the results are fine, but when I add a dummy for each rank my output becomes skewed:

```
Number of obs =    972
F( 18,   241) =       .
Prob > F      =       .
R-squared     =  0.2478
```

Any ideas why my F becomes a '.'?

Comment: Without seeing all your controls, it's hard to point to the actual culprit. But it looks like what you've done is removed the variation within a cluster. Essentially, you have too many controls and not enough clusters.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks for the response. I am VERY new to quantitative analysis, it Stata was just covered in my first statistics course. Can you explain a little more what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have 241 clusters. 241 - 1 = 240 is the most coefficients for which you can estimate the full variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients.

If you have $m$ clusters and you add in $m-1$ dummy/indicator variables/fixed effects (all mean the same thing), then you have at least $m$ coefficients in your model including the intercept. Since $m > m-1$, you cannot estimate the variance-covariance matrix when you cluster at the same level as a set of fixed effects in your model.

Without a full-rank variance-covariance matrix, you are not able to test the hypothesis that all the coefficients are 0, which is what the *F* test is reporting.

The individual hypothesis tests may be okay, but you effectively have a small number of observations (equal to the number of clusters) relative to the number of coefficients. The standard errors are only valid as the number of clusters (minus the number of coefficients being estimated) goes to infinity.

Comment: Great answer, and it makes perfect sense! Regarding your last point, can I use the coefficients? If so it helps my story, that is why I am wondering. Or, is there a way to test if their OK? If so is it common to report that this happened. Lastly, what is the difference between using a fixed effect for something versus clustering on it and is there a test to see which is better to use?